# Showing compressed zip folder is invalid

Tags: typescript

Here i'm using of `type` want to download the format file, while downloading csv file I'm not facing any issue ,but in zip i'm facing an isssue like this. Please help me Thanks in advance

[image]

```
 export const DownloadJsonReport = (data: BlobPart, type: string, fileName: string) => {
 const report = document.createElement('a');
 const csvContent = data;
 const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type });
 const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  report.href = url;
  report.setAttribute('download', fileName);
  report.click();
};

  const DownloadActionClick = useCallback(() => {
  const data = // api calling//
  if (type === 'csv) {
      DownloadJsonReport(
        data as BlobPart,
        'text/csv;charset=utf-8;',
        `${id}report.csv`,
      );
    },
   else {
      DownloadJsonReport(
        data as BlobPart,
        'application/json',
        `${id}report.zip`,
      );
    },   
 }, [
type,
]);
```

Comment: Which library are using for the `zip` file? Also please add the part of your code where you create the `zip` file.

Comment: i'm not using any library, `DownloadJsonReport` from this i'm generating the zip

Comment: Then you are not creating a `zip` file. you are just saving with `zip` extension. you need a library to create it for you.